# Finding a number in a text file and outputting that line of data

Tags: c++

I'm having trouble looping through the content of a text file, searching for a number and then once found, outputting the data on the line which the number exists.

At the moment, no matter what number you specify, it will always output the first line of the text file.

```
cout << endl << "Please enter a staff members ID: ";
cin >> id;
do
{
    inStream.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    getline(inStream, line);
    if (line.find(id))
    {
        cout << endl << line;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << endl << "Error. Could not find the staff member.\n";
    }
} while (id != id);
```

Comment: if line.find doesn't find it, it returns std::string::npos. Problem is, this is equal to -1...

Comment: You should show the declarations of any identifiers you use in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put the seekg line outside the do while loop.
inStream.seekg(0, ios::beg);

id != id ? :-)

Also put in a break condition (EOF check) if you don't want an infinite loop.